# Drop-wizard request response logging

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, dropwizard, jersey-client

I want to log each request and response in dropwizard into different files. For example I want all the requests to be logged in  **/var/log/applicationname-request.log** and all responses into **/var/log/applicationname-response.log**

Is there any way in which we can achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately DropWizard currently doesn't support this natively. See [this lively discussion](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/567) for more information.

Fortunately there's a workaround if you're willing to forego configuring logging with DropWizard all together. Somewhere in your `run` method call the following code to reset the logging and reconfigure it using sfl4j's standard mechanism:

```java
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
context.reset();
ContextInitializer initializer = new ContextInitializer(context);
initializer.autoConfig();
```

Then you can configure logging by adding `logback.xml` to your classpath and configuring it something like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="REQUEST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/applicationname-request.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RESPONSE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/applicationame-response.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.example.request">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="REQUEST" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.example.response">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RESPONSE" />
  </logger>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Then you can grab those corresponding loggers in your resource and log away:

```java
static final Logger REQUEST_LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.example.request");
static final Logger RESPONSE_LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.example.response");
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine this way. Can we bind this logger in drop-wizard configurations ? So, that drop-wizard can use this for its internal logging.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to setup this logger in the DropWizard configuration because that will get lost when you reinitialize the logging. But you could add a separate logger for DropWizard classes in logback.xml

Comment: @condit I think this is outdated... Is it?